# AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID " XYZXYZXYZ"

Tags: azure, api, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

We build an application using Microsoft graph api's. We register app using our personal account for authentication in azure portal. All things are working perfectly when user authenticate using his personal login credential. But when user use their organizational account for authentication e.g "kaz@deltaforcegroup.co.uk" then it authenticate but it gives an error

[image]

how can we resolve this issue? which permissions we have to add for avoid this dialogue box?

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this issue for ***Need admin approval*** Make sure to allow user consent for application

***Sign into the Azure portal as a Global Administrator ->Enterprise applications -> Consent and permissions under security -> user consent setting -> allow as below and save***

[image]

> **> [AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID**

This issue frequently happens when you failed to grant admin permission to the scope, please check few workarounds:

***In your Azure Portal -> Azure AD-> App Registrations -> Your App -> Expose an API*** ***->Try to add application ID URI -> Add scope and client application as below***
[image]

*After adding expose an Api. Try to add API permission to access your app* ***In your azure portal -> Api permission under manage -> add permission ->select MY APIS -> select your app -> add permission ->make sure to grant admin consent like below***

[image]
[image]

Please check this ***Reference:*** [resolving-need-admin-approval-error](https://www.codetwo.com/kb/resolving-need-admin-approval-error/) and similar [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67549291/interactionrequiredautherror-aadsts65001-the-user-or-administrator-has-not-con) by ***carl zhao***

Comment: i had applied all of these but which permission we should add to access data of authenticate user for example you add IMR_key permission. In my case which permission i should add?

Comment: You can [grant admin consent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/grant-admin-consent) to whole tenant using admin consent URL

Comment: kindly tell me one thing that can we make an app on azure portal using personal account?

Comment: Yes, we can create an app in personal account

Comment: i have done all of thing which you mention above but issue is same

Comment: Please check this [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/571628/aadsts65001-the-user-or-administrator-has-not-cons-1.html) make sure to grant admin